# Why are there soo many HTTP connections when using Convergence?

Tags: tls, firefox

I installed Convergence on Firefox 9.0.1:

http://convergence.io/

but... after I installed/enabled it when I visit a HTTPS only-site there are many-many HTTP traffic to the notary servers. Why? shouldn't those connections be encrypted?? Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: Have you looked at the content of those requests? Do they need to be encrypted or not?

Comment: I have no idea that they need encryption or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notary protocol includes both HTTP and HTTPS traffic: the HTTP part is used for the anonymous notary proxy.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if all the HTTP traffic goes through a HTTP proxy that can modify it's content?

Comment: On the one hand, if you believe the designers of a security protocol are capable of the sort of bone-headed mistake you are thinking of, then you shouldn't use it, whether they made such a mistake or not.

Comment: On the other hand, they send the important stuff over HTTPS, and it's signed as well.

Comment: And on the gripping hand, I haven't done a detailed analysis of the protocol (and am not really qualified to) - and certainly subverting the anonymous notary proxy scheme would be something of interest to an attacker.

Comment: Having no real idea how notary services operate outside of base theory, but being a software dev: opening both HTTPS and HTTP would allow you to detect if there is proxy tampering going on, not sure if this is outside of the scope of their operation though.